# Legendre expansion of $r(x) = f(x)/g(x)$ using a finite number of samples from $f(x)$ and $g(x)$

Tags: st.statistics, na.numerical-analysis, legendre-polynomials

I have two finite sets of events $\{x_1, ..., x_N\}$ and $\{y_1, ..., y_N\}$ that are sampled from the PDFs $f(x)$ and $g(x)$, respectively, where $x \in [-1,+1]$. I want to estimate the Legendre expansion of $r(x) = f(x)/g(x)$ using these events. What is the best method? (Note that $g(x)\neq0$ over $[-1,1]$)

Comment: Hi Sam, welcome to MO. As it is, the question is not clear. You need to evluate $r$'s Legendre expansion by a finite (different) number of samples from $f$ and $y$? I think it is better (for you and us) to devide the question in two: (1) How to evaluate $r$ if you *know* the expansions of $f$ and $g$. (2) How bad or good is this method if $f$ and $g$'s expansions are only determined using monte carlo

Comment: Also, I think there's a good chance to get a good in stack.scicomp

Comment: Hi Amir, thanks for your fast response! Yes that's correct - I have a finite number of samples from $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ and want to describe the Legendre expansion of $r(x) = f(x) / g(x)$.

Comment: Good. Try and edit your questions so that'd be apparent. As it is, it's really hard to understand that.

Comment: Erm... Legendre expansion makes sense only on a finite interval. So far the supports of your $f$ and $g$ are not restricted to anything and, moreover, the ratio $f/g$ is not obliged to be even finite a.e., forget the integrability. Some a priori assumptions have to be introduced to make the question meaningful, in which case it is a good idea to spell them out.

Comment: Good point. Have added additional details to the question, thanks!

Comment: Alas, you need either more assumptions or some change in the formulation: dropping $g$ to near $0$ on a very short interval does not change the sampling but destroys the expansion of $f/g$ completely (in other words, the way it is posed the problem is terribly unstable). Forget about the full expansion for now, just think of the first term $\frac 12\int_{-1}^1 \frac fg$. Try to pose the question so that at least this subproblem has a decent answer or use it to figure out what you want from your estimator (i.e., define the notion of "best").